# how to convert 2d array into 1d array after minmax scaling

Tags: python

I did my feature minmax scaling, previously the shape is (10000,) after i scaled it with MinMaxScaler it the shape changed into (10000,1). I need the shape to be (10000,) or else somehow my Keras model cannot process it due to different shape of the dimension. How to turn the shape into (10000,) again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here a possibility

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

X = np.random.uniform(-10,10, 10000)
print(X.shape) # (10000,)

scaler = MinMaxScaler()
scaled_X = scaler.fit_transform(X.reshape(-1,1))
print(scaled_X.shape) # (10000,1)

scaled_X = scaled_X.ravel()
print(scaled_X.shape) # (10000,)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try using this, I don't know if this is helpful but I thought to post it.

```
a = a.reshape(12,1)
print(a.shape)
array_1d = a.flatten()
print(array_1d.shape)
```

output

```
(12, 1)
(12,)
```